# Problemas con ProgressDialog?

Tags: android

Bueno tengo el siguiente problema que creo que estoy en mi logica el problema es el siguiente genero un ProgressDialog que al finalizar o terminar con el .dismiss() abro o genero otro ProgressDialog con las mismas caracteristicas adjunto el codigo hasta cierto punto realiza las funciones pero llega un punto que se hace un bucle interminable alguna idea para que el algoritmo se mas eficiente:

```
public void Export() throws InterruptedException {

    final ProgressDialog barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(local);
    updateBarHandler = new Handler();
    barProgressDialog.setTitle("Exportando Datos ...");
    barProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String mqry = "select * from tabla1 WHERE UpdateToServer = 1";

    final Cursor crs = db.rawQuery(mqry,null);
    int noRegs = crs.getCount();
    if(noRegs > 0){

        barProgressDialog.setMessage("Enviando datos ...");
        barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
        barProgressDialog.setMax(noRegs);
        barProgressDialog.show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (barProgressDialog.getProgress() <= barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                while (crs.moveToNext()) {
                                    int _i = crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex("ID_mov"));
                                    GPro gpro = new GPro();
                                    if (_i == 0) {
                                        gpro.execute(crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex("_id")), 1);
                                    } else {
                                        gpro.execute(crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex("_id")),2);
                                    }
                                    barProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        if (barProgressDialog.getProgress() == barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
                            barProgressDialog.dismiss();

                            Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                            h.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                       Export();
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    Log.e("Registro de Actividad", ignored.toString());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }else{
        barProgressDialog.setMessage("No hay Datos que exportar");
        barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        barProgressDialog.show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                barProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            ExpoPre();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Al terminar se vuelve a abrir otro dialogo?

Comment: Así es..  bueno así se me ocurrió hacerlo y al parecer estoy mal

Comment: Algun mensaje en el logcat?

Answer (score 1):

veo que los Dialogos se crean dentro de Threads pero estos Threads en ocasiones los detienes o inicias los dialogos despues de determinados segundos. Te aconsejaria en este loop, agregar afuera el `barProgressDialog.dismiss();` para asegurar que cuando termine el proceso la instancia del barProgressDialog se cierre.

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (barProgressDialog.getProgress() <= barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
              }

           barProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: buenos que ocupo barrer una tablas y mostrar el dialgo para el avance de los que estoy subiendo y si no tiene datos la tablas que muestre que no hay datos y pase a la siguiente tabla, el diaologo cuando no tiene datos se cierra si problemas y avanza, pero cuando tiene datos si envia el detalle que no sigue avanzando pero probare con tu idea puede que sea mi logica de como abro y cirreo los dialigos

Comment: ya probe pero no hace nada se termina,